# console producer is trying to connect non-leader and non-replica/isr node in Apache kafka

Tags: ssl, apache-kafka

My kafka cluster is having 9 nodes .

Bcz I am trying to implement SSL, I am currently trying to set up SSL on only 1 node.

Now as I have done SSL setup for node with id 1001 and to test this, I created a topic 'SSLtest' which has leader as well as replica on 1001 only.

When I try to push data from console producer on same machine to the topic 'SSLtest' (i.e 1001), it tries to connect machine 1006 as log says :

```
Error when handling request {topics=[SSLtest],allow_auto_topic_creation=true} (kafka.server.KafkaApis)

kafka.common.BrokerEndPointNotAvailableException: End point with listener name SSL not found for broker 1006.
```

Why can't it push data to 1001 directly. What is it trying to do on 1006.

Comment: You need to post your configuration as well.

Comment: @GiorgosMyrianthous I got answer to my question that - we can't apply SSL on some nodes of a cluster, we have to apply SSL on all nodes. SSL is either all or none :) thanks alot